# React not loading state properly on mount during axios call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Basically I am making a basic react App that is grabbing some data from a DB and I am stuck on the basic setup.

My intention is to have my state contain the response from my server querying my databse.

My response is 100% working and sending the data back as expected from the axios call, however the state is never getting update.

EDIT : I am attempting to pass the movies down the chain to a Component called MovieList, I have provided the code for that as well.

App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import MovieList from './MovieList.jsx';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {allMovies: []};
   
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var that = this;
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/movies')
      .then( res => {
        that.setState({allMovies: res.data});
      })
      .catch( err => {
        console.log(`Err @ [ App.jsx - componentDidMount ] ::: ${err}`);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <MovieList movies={this.state.allMovies} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

MovieList.jsx

```
     import React from 'react';

class MovieList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
        console.log(this.props); //EMPTY OBJECT MOVIES DIDN'T GET INTO PROPS
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Test</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default MovieList;
```

NOTE : I also logged the props on mount and attempted to render them and they were empty.

Basically if I try to pass down this.state.allMovies or console.log it, its always just the initial empty array.

Maybe I don't understand how async setting the state can be done? I took a similar approach on my last school project and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: In your movies component it should be  `this.props.movies` i guess.

Answer (score 1):

You don't await the axios promise to resolve, so you simply are logging what the state is when the component mounts. Use one of the following to log updated react state.

Use `componentDidUpdate` to log the updated state.

```
componentDidMount() {
  console.log(this.state);
}
```

Use the `setState` callback function to log the state

```
componentDidMount() {
  var that = this;
  axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/movies')
    .then( res => {
      console.log(res.data);
      that.setState(
        { allMovies: [res.data] },
        () => console.log(this.state), // <-- setState callback function
      );
    })
    .catch( err => {
      console.log(`Err @ [ App.jsx - componentDidMount ] ::: ${err}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: I am actually passing it down to another component like so " <MovieList movies={this.state.allMovies} /> and it is just showing up as an empty array. I have also already tried logging the state after the call like you did above and it yielded the same result.

Comment: @chrisalopez1337 So the issue is in `MovieList` then? It isn't "seeing" the updated state that is passed as a prop to it? Can you try creating a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue and share here?

Comment: I updated so you can see my movielist component. The props are just an empty array and dont contain the updated state which is what lead me to believe the state was not getting updated on mount.

Comment: @chrisalopez1337 Similar situation, the constructor is run only once, so on the initial render it receives the empty array passed to it. Additionally, while in the constructor, `this.props` isn't really defined yet, if you want to log received props then use the `props` argument passed to the constructor, i.e. `console.log(props)`. Use a lifecycle function like `componentDidUpdate` in the child component to log props as they update and rerender the component.

Comment: @chrisalopez1337 The constructor should be a pure function with zero side-effect... use `componentDidMount` to issue any side-effects, like logging, when the component is mounted.

Comment: okay that makes sense, and I am surely getting closer to the solution here. So when I used componentDidUpdate() and logged this.props is was up to date. How can I access this in the initial render though? I made a var test = '' || this.props.movies[0].title. And if I log that in the compenentDidUpdate() it is visible, but it throws an error when I attempt to render it.

Comment: @chrisalopez1337 It throws because on the initial render `this.props.movies[0]` is undefined. You can use optional chaining `this.props.movies[0]?.title` to guard against null/undefined values. `movies` is an array, so typically you would map the result, i.e. `this.props.movies.map(movie => (<div>{movie.title}</div>))`, and if you want to display a "loading" state then you can conditionally render it, like `this.props.movies.length ? this.props.movies.map(movie => (<div>{movie.title}</div>)) : '...Loading Movies'`.

Comment: Got it working! Thanks man I really appreciate you taking the time to explain it and help me debug.

Answer (score 1):

You'll never see it in your constructor, because when your component is instantiated, it's done so with an empty array.

You will see it if you do a `console.log(this.props)` in `componentDidUpdate` or `render` however.

This is because when `App` is mounted, your component passes a movies prop of `[]` to `MovieList`. After the movies return from the server (and you update the state of `App`), `App` will render again and pass the array returned from the server, causing your `MovieList` component to render again. It's `constructor` won't be called, because it's already instantiated, but `MovieList` will call `componentDidUpdate` and `render` again.

```js
class MovieList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props); // you'll see this get logged twice - once with an empty array for movies and once with the movies returned from the server.
      
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Test</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```